# Случайно удалил проект Unity

Tags: unity3d, файлы, файловая-система, восстановление

Честно, не знаю как это произошло, но вероятнее всего это или из-за ошибки hamachi (после этой ошибки пришлось переустанавливать стим и все игры из стима) или из-за обновления unity hub с 3.0 до 3.2 (видел схожую проблему связанную именно с обновлением хаба в интернете). Все это произошло примерно недели 2 назад, а обнаружил проблему только сегодня. Пытался найти проект по всему диску. Корзину, по своей глупости, очищал примерно дня 3 назад. Даже в aseprite, где я поставил сохранение спрайтов в папку проекта, она пропала. Есть ли какие-нибудь способы восстановления? Буду очень благодарен.
OC windows 10 home
Точка восстановления есть,  но файлы диска не откатывает. Места предостаточно

Comment: Добавь информацию о версии ОС, сколько свободного места на диске и есть ли точки восстановления? посмотри и поищи через https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shadow_copy_view.html

Comment: Добавил,  точка восстановления есть, но,  как я понял,  файлы она не откатила

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, SystemRestore не трогает пользовательские файлы. Но в теневой копии есть всё.

Поищи через nirsoft.net/utils/shadow_copy_view.html (или подобную программу)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для поиска удобно пользоваться Everything  https://www.voidtools.com/downloads/

На будущее: для подобных проектов их удобно хранить на облачном диске, у них есть возможность откатить на несколько недель назад любой файл.